# ssh hangs on osx client after Entering interactive session

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, remote-desktop, rsync

I am trying to connect to a remote server (remote server running `linux`, local client running `osx`) through `ssh`, but the connection hangs after `Entering interactive session`.

- I can `sftp remote` successfully
- I can `scp remote:something .`
- I can do port forwarding through `ssh -fN remote` works correctly (the setting for port forwarding are in the `.ssh/config`)
- I connect to the server through `vnc` using the above port forwarding
- `rsync` ALSO HANGS after Entering interactive session.

I am using the following configuration:

```
ServerAliveInterval 120

Host            *
ForwardX11       yes

Host            remote
HostName        remote.address.uk
HostKeyAlias    remote.address.uk
User            myusername
LocalForward    localhost:5903 remote:5904
LocalForward    localhost:5902 remote:5901
TCPKeepAlive    yes
IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Because somewhere it is claimed that this is due to local files on the remote server, I have removed all the `.bash*` `.cshrc` `.profile`

I have noticed that this behaviour does not happen when I try to connect from my Linux box (that I run as a virtual machine in my `osx`). Also the connect hangs from my `osx` when I try to connect to another remote server.

What can I check for debugging this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that X forwarding is broken on my `osx`. I have disabled it and now I can connect